# Prove that $ \ \forall x \exists y \ P(x,y) \ $ and $ \ \exists y \forall x \ P(x,y) \ $ are not equivalent

Tags: logic

Prove that $ \ \forall x \exists y \ P(x,y) \ $ and $ \ \exists y \forall x \ P(x,y) \ $ are not logically not equivalent  in the **domain** $ \ \{-1,0,1 \} \ $.

**Answer:**

Let,

$ x=\{-1,0,1 \} \\ y=\{-1,0,1 \} $

Let $ P(x,y) \ $ be the property such that $ x +y  \ $ is even number.

Then $ \forall x \exists y \ P(x,y) \ $ is true.

Because,

If $ x=-1 \ $ , then take $ y=1 \ $ such that $ x + y=0 \ $ is even

If $ x=0 \ $ , then take $ y=0  \ $ , such that $ x + y=0 \ $ is even

If $ x=1 \ $ , then take $ y=1  \ $ such that $ x + y =2 \ $ is even

But $ \ \exists y \forall x \ P(x,y) \ $ is  $ False $

**Am I right ?**

**I need help.**

Comment: Correct! Good job!

Comment: Yes this works -- except the notation $x=\{-1,0,1\}$ is wrong and shouldn't be there. And an even easier property to use would be to let $P(x,y)$ be $x=y$.

Comment: You could have added why it is true that $\exists y\forall x\,P(x,y)$ is false. Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: can I get any other easier property with ?

Comment: This is a terrible application of the notation. The operators are commutative in the classical sense. You are instead comparing $\forall x \exists y$ and $\forall x \exists ! y$ which are by definition totally distinct and you dont have to prove *anything*.

Comment: @hyprfrcb Everything you said in the previous statement is wrong.

Comment: @mabmath I think you mean "for $x \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$" (similarly for $y$), otherwise that statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: mabmath, you were the author of the duplicated question as well.  DO NOT EVER REPOST the SAME QUESTION!

Comment: Sir it not duplicated , please you can check minutely  it that both question differs by the conditions on $ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $. They are different questions.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, please unmark it.  The other question uses $\exists x \forall y$ instead of $\exists y \forall x$, and it is not just an alpha transform.

Comment: Agreed, this is not a duplicate.